# USB Flash drive listed by lsblk but fdisk/gparted fails to open

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, fdisk

Background: I want to `dd` an .iso to the device and then boot from it.

The USB Flash Drive seems to be corrupted in some way. Here is what I know so far:
Ouput of `dmesg | grep -i usb` contains the following:

```
[ 7487.597557] usb 2-1.2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 7487.597560] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: JetFlash
[ 7487.597564] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 09021000000000000890585749
[ 7487.597980] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 7487.600249] scsi host15: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[ 7579.925290] usb 2-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
```

So I assume the drive is correctly recognized by the kernel.
Also `lsusb` is listing the device:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
```

And `lsblk` too:

```
sdg      8:96   1  14.7G  0 disk 
└─sdg1   8:97   1  14.7G  0 part /media/pc/D89D-344C
```

The device has been mounted automatically. In order to open it with fdisk, I unmount it using `umount /media/pc/D89D-344C`

But when I try to use fdisk, to repartition the device `sudo fdisk /dev/sdg` I get an error:

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdg: No such device or address
```

Using `gparted` or `dd` results in the same error message.

EDIT: I checked the kernel logs with `dmesg -f kern -wH`

Logs appearing upon connecting the device.

```
[15677.249968] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[15677.347877] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=8564, idProduct=1000
[15677.347883] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[15677.347887] usb 2-1.2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[15677.347891] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: JetFlash
[15677.347894] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 09021000000000000890585749
[15677.348361] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[15677.350849] scsi host18: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[15678.351408] scsi 18:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 16GB   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[15678.352272] sd 18:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[15678.353107] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] 30883840 512-byte logical blocks: (15.8 GB/14.7 GiB)
[15678.353772] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off
[15678.353778] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[15678.355509] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] No Caching mode page found
[15678.355517] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] Assuming drive cache: write through
[15678.361642]  sdg: sdg1
[15678.364016] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI removable disk
[15678.575133] FAT-fs (sdg1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

executing `umount` then leads to following kernel logs:

```
[15769.457966] usb 2-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[15800.488587] usb 2-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[15810.652140] usb 2-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[15826.815308] usb 2-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[15826.983416] usb 2-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[15837.146944] usb 2-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[15837.240453] sd 18:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[15837.240468] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[15837.240475] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 08 01 00 00 01 00
[15837.240479] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 2049
[15837.240485] Buffer I/O error on dev sdg1, logical block 1, lost async page write
[15837.240501] sd 18:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[15837.240506] sd 18:0:0:0: killing request
```

Hope this problem can be solved. This is my last USB flash drive.

Thanks for any hints and ideas.

Comment: I suspect this `I/O error` when you `umount` your USB makes it go offline (notice `rejecting I/O to offline device`). At this moment `/dev/sdg*` disappear. So there's really "no such device". Run `ls -l /dev/sdg*` before and just *after* `umount` to confirm this. If I'm right your USB flash drive is probably faulty. But have you tried other USB ports?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `/dev/sdg` is an actual device node. If something accidentally created a garbage file or link before you connected the disk, the kernel won't overwrite it. (And you won't notice because the whole-disk node isn't used for mounting; only partition nodes are needed.)

Run `ls -l /dev/sdg*` and make sure the reported "major, minor" numbers exactly match the "MAJ:MIN" column in *lsblk*. (The type also needs to be `b` of course.)

If you find anything odd, just remove it; the correct device node will be created after reconnecting the drive.

Comment: Tested it but unfortunately everything appears to be a correct device node. When the device is disconnected `ls -l /dev/sdg*` find nothing.When the device is connected, the correct nodes are found. All the columns look fine too. They match `lsblk` output.
Can it be possible that the nodes are corrupted upon creation ?